# Need correct inline jQuery syntax to change fancybox dimensions

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, fancybox

I'm using `fancybox` to successfully display `iframes` on a page. I need to be able to change the dimensions of the `fancybox` `iframe` for different uses.  My understanding is that inline `jQuery` is likely the best option to modify the `CSS`, but I can't get it to have any effect.

If I change these `CSS` dimension values in the `CSS` file and republish it, it works just fine – but it works for all `fancyboxes` on the page.  These dimensions are the ones that I need to change inline for different instances of `fancyboxes`.

I've tried to add inline `jQuery` right before this html that modifies the `fancybox` CSS`enter code here` dimensions for this `fancybox`, but either I'm getting the `jQuery` syntax wrong or I'm placing it in the wrong place. Here's an example one of the many `jQuery` calls I've tried with the html based on online suggestions:

Please help with any corrections/suggestions!

Edit: The CSS in the file is working.  Is it ok to use `".fancybox-slide--iframe .fancybox-content"` in the inline jQuery call?

Edit2: Could it be a timing issue? Could the markup be running before the jQuery has changed the CSS?

```js
$(".fancybox-slide--iframe .fancybox-content").css("width", "1200px");
```

```css
.fancybox-slide--iframe .fancybox-content {
  width  : auto;
  height : auto;
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 500px;
  max-width  : 100%;
  max-height : 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 16px #999;
    border: 3px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-track-container">

   <a class="text add-track-container2" data-fancybox data-src="../../test/ytsearch/index.html" href="javascript:;">

      <img class="add-track-icon" src="common/images/desktop_icons/addcircle50.png" alt="Add Track" />

   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: **Syntax Error:** `.css("width": "1200px")` => `.css("width", "1200px")` / *fixed on edit.* / Also no need to use `px` it count as `px` by default

Comment: I tried that syntax first and it doesn't work. The syntax shown is from W3 for multiple parameters ...which I was trying too but forgot to change back. I tried with and without px just to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I wasn't attaching to fancybox correctly. Once I fixed that, all was good. Here is an example of how to apply different fancybox settings to multiple DIVs/Classes for the next person looking for a simple example ...put this at the bottom of your page, right before :

```
           <script>
                $('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
                    toolbar  : false,
                    smallBtn : true,
                    afterClose: function () {
                    parent.location.reload(true);
                }
                })

                $(".log-reg").fancybox({
                    toolbar  : false,
                    smallBtn : true,
                    iframe : {
                        css : {
                            height : '500px'
                        }
                    }
                });
            </script>
```